# Apostrophe usage in job titles

Tags: apostrophe

Why is apostrophe not used in job titles such as "Production Assistant" or "Production Engineer". My understanding about these roles is that people are part or are members of the production. Why not "Production's Assistant" or "Production's Engineer"?

Comment: Think of it as "assistant for the purpose of production", not "belonging to the production".

Comment: What @stangdon said. "Production" is an attributive nominal (sometimes called "nominal adjunct", "qualifying nominal", etc.); look up that term if you're unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, *production*, also called an **attributive noun**, describes *engineer*.  It is like an adjective but not exactly one.

[attributive noun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)

> a noun adjunct, attributive noun, qualifying noun, noun (pre)modifier, or apposite noun is an optional noun that modifies another noun; it is a noun functioning as a pre-modifier in a noun phrase. For example, in the phrase "chicken soup" the noun adjunct "chicken" modifies the noun "soup"

We use possessive nouns more commonly for living things, and less so for non-living things.   More explanations are shown below.

[Possessive noun](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/possessive_noun.htm)

> Possessive Nouns with Inanimate Objects

> [I]t is possible for inanimate things (e.g. "a book") and even intangible things (e.g. "a day") to possess objects from a grammatical perspective.

> A car door (best version)

> A door of a car (possible but awkward)

> A car's door (possible but still awkward)

The above guide shows that possessive nouns for non-living things are possible in some cases.

In our example, however, *Production's Engineer* is rarely used; it is not found in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=production+engineer%2Cproduction%27s+engineer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true)